# Django: Restrict staff user to give more permissions to a group than his own

Tags: django

I've created a Django app having multiple types of users.

There is one Superuser who can access all the data and do the modification stuff. There are few staff users, who have limited access, mostly of view but can add new users and groups.

Below is the group permission for the staff user. He can add a new group but cannot change, view or delete existing.

[image]

But when I try to create a new group, he can assign all the possible permissions to the new group, even though he doesn't have those permissions himself. Below is the view he can see when creating a new group.

[image]

How can I only show those permissions which the staff user himself have and not to show complete options?

I am using **Django 2.1**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Create groups with various permissions
Prevent add or delete groups

```
    #other imports
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

    class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
        list_display = ('username', 'email', 'is_staff')
        list_filter = ('is_staff',)
        #this displays after initial user creation for additional information
        fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active', 'groups')}),
        )
        # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
        # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
        add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
        )
        search_fields = ('username',)
        ordering = ('username',)

    #unregister the default user admin
    admin.site.unregister(User)
    # Now register the new UserAdmin...
    admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

This way, the user can not get additional permissions